# I am getting error "unable to initialize libusb: -99" on executing lsusb command on WSL2 Ubuntu app on my Windows

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zephyr-rtos, lsusb

I am getting errror "**unable to initialize libusb: -99**" on executing **lsusb** command on WSL2 Ubuntu app on my Windows 10 . Please help. I am basically trying to flash Zephyr as simple  Hello world application on my reel_board by connecting reel_board via USB cable to my PC. Whenever I pluggin my board to PC, I am not seeing any ttydevice like /dev/ttyUSB* or /dev/ttyACM* directory anywhere in my /dev folder which I should be seeing.

I thought it might be permission issue related to udev rules. Now to set permission rules i need vendor ID and product ID that can only be retrieved using **lsusb** command which is not working for me  .

Please advice

Comment: This error got resolved by Window update latest build version > 18917  and using correct version of Ubuntu 20.04 from ms Store instead of just Ubuntu

Comment: There's no support for USB on WSL2... I had to rollback to WSL1 and now I can use the serial ports listed in "Device Manager" as COM# to their respective ttyS#, but I can't for example flash my Tiva Launchpad using LM4FLASH.